How to Prevent Resizing Desktop Icon Window with Hotkey in Windows Application?
I've got a program that resizes the foreground window when a hotkey is entered:
// Sample.cpp

#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include "Sample.h"

int WINAPI wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE     hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR        lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int           nCmdShow) {

    // Register main window class
    LPCTSTR mainWndClassName = MAIN_WND_CLASS_NAME;
    LPCTSTR mainWndTitle     = APP_TITLE;

    WNDCLASSEX mainWndClass = {};

    mainWndClass.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    mainWndClass.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    mainWndClass.hInstance     = hInstance;
    mainWndClass.hIcon         = (HICON) ICON;
    mainWndClass.lpszClassName = mainWndClassName;

    RegisterClassEx(&mainWndClass);

    // Generate main window
    HWND mainWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        mainWndClassName,
        mainWndTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_THICKFRAME,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_MESSAGE,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    if (mainWnd == NULL) {
        return BAD_HWND;
    }

    // Register hotkeys
    // TODO [L]: Refactor
    if (!RegisterHotKey(mainWnd,
                        ID_HK_ALT_CEN_WND_1,
                        MOD_CONTROL | MOD_SHIFT,
                        '1')) {
        return BAD_KEY;
    }

    // Start message loop
    MSG msg = {};

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // Unregister hotkeys
    UnregisterHotKey(NULL, ID_HK_ALT_CEN_WND_1);

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

// Sample.h

#pragma once

#include "framework.h"

/* ********** FORWARD DECLARATIONS ********** */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

// MESSAGE HANDLERS

void HandleHotKeyMessage(HWND, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void HandlePaintMessage(HWND);

//  HELPER FUNCTIONS

LONG CenterWindow(HWND,
                  LONG flag          = NULL,
                  LONG newHWndWidth  = 80,
                  LONG newHWndHeight = 90);
LONG ResizeWindow(HWND, LONG, LONG);

/* ********** FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ********** */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND   hWnd,
                            UINT   uMsg,
                            WPARAM wParam,
                            LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_PAINT: {
            HandlePaintMessage(hWnd);
            break;
        }
        case WM_HOTKEY: {
            HandleHotKeyMessage(hWnd, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

// MESSAGE HANDLERS

void HandleHotKeyMessage(HWND hWnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    // TODO [H]: Fix. Prevent desktop from resizing when hotkey is pressed from
    // within an active desktop.
    HWND foregroundWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

    switch (wParam) {
        case ID_HK_ALT_CEN_WND_1: {
            CenterWindow(foregroundWnd, MOD_WND_SIZE, 20, 30);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void HandlePaintMessage(HWND hWnd) {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps = {};

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}

//  HELPER FUNCTIONS

LONG CenterWindow(HWND hWnd,
                  LONG flag,
                  LONG newHWndWidth,
                  LONG newHWndHeight) {
    if (hWnd == NULL) {
        return BAD_HWND;
    }

    // Get window dimensions
    RECT rect = {};

    if (GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect)) {
        LONG hWndWidth, hWndHeight;
        LONG workAreaWidth, workAreaHeight;
        LONG leftEdgeXCoord, topEdgeYCoord;

        // Get work area dimensions
        RECT workArea = {};

        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, NULL, &workArea, NULL);

        workAreaWidth  = workArea.right - workArea.left;
        workAreaHeight = workArea.bottom - workArea.top;

        // Compute centered window dimensions
        if (flag == MOD_WND_SIZE) {
            hWndWidth  = (LONG) std::ceil(workAreaWidth * (newHWndWidth / 100.0));
            hWndHeight = (LONG) std::ceil(workAreaHeight * (newHWndHeight / 100.0));
        } else {
            hWndWidth  = rect.right - rect.left;
            hWndHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        }

        // Compute edge coordinates used to center window
        leftEdgeXCoord = (workAreaWidth - hWndWidth) / 2;
        topEdgeYCoord  = (workAreaHeight - hWndHeight) / 2;

        // Undo window maximization if necessary
        if (IsZoomed(hWnd) && flag == MOD_WND_SIZE) {
            ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
        }

        // Reposition window
        MoveWindow(hWnd,
                   leftEdgeXCoord,
                   topEdgeYCoord,
                   hWndWidth,
                   hWndHeight,
                   TRUE);

        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        return BAD_RECT_READ;
    }
}

LONG ResizeWindow(HWND hWnd, LONG widthChange, LONG heightChange) {
    if (hWnd == NULL) {
        return BAD_HWND;
    }

    // Get window dimensions
    RECT rect = {};

    if (GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect)) {
        LONG newHWndWidth, newHWndHeight;
        LONG leftEdgeXCoord, topEdgeYCoord;
        LONG minWidth, minHeight;

        // Compute new window dimensions with change factor taken into account
        newHWndWidth  = (rect.right - rect.left) + widthChange;
        newHWndHeight = (rect.bottom - rect.top) + heightChange;

        // Get work area dimensions
        RECT workArea = {};

        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, NULL, &workArea, NULL);

        // Compute minimum window dimensions as a percentage of work area
        // dimensions
        minWidth  = (LONG) std::ceil((workArea.right - workArea.left) * 0.2);
        minHeight = (LONG) std::ceil((workArea.bottom - workArea.left) * 0.2);

        // Adjust window dimensions if minimum is reached
        if (newHWndWidth <= minWidth) {
            newHWndWidth = minWidth;
        }
        if (newHWndHeight <= minHeight) {
            newHWndHeight = minHeight;
        }

        // Compute edge coordinates used to center window
        leftEdgeXCoord = rect.left;
        topEdgeYCoord  = rect.top;

        // Adjust edge coordinates if window is resized
        if (newHWndWidth != minWidth) {
            leftEdgeXCoord = rect.left - (widthChange / 2);
        }
        if (newHWndHeight != minHeight) {
            topEdgeYCoord = rect.top - (heightChange / 2);
        }

        // TODO [H]: Account for misalignment of centering when minimum dimensions
        // are reached. Find a way to indicate when minimum is reached as to
        // not recalculate edge coordinates. (FEATURE, NOT BUG...)

        // Undo window maximization if necessary
        if (IsZoomed(hWnd)) {
            ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
        }

        // Reposition window
        MoveWindow(hWnd,
                   leftEdgeXCoord,
                   topEdgeYCoord,
                   newHWndWidth,
                   newHWndHeight,
                   TRUE);

        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        return BAD_RECT_READ;
    }
}

// framework.h

// header.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files

#pragma once

#include "Resource.h"
#include "targetver.h"

// Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

// Windows Header Files
#include <windows.h>

// C RunTime Header Files
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <cmath>

// Macros
// Hotkey IDs
#define ID_HK_ALT_CEN_WND_1 4

// Modifiers
#define MOD_WND_SIZE 100

// Constants
#define WND_CHANGE_SIZE     50

#define APP_TITLE           L"ReSize"
#define MAIN_WND_CLASS_NAME L"Default"

// Program status return values
#define SUCCESS       0

#define BAD_HWND      400
#define BAD_KEY       401
#define BAD_RECT_READ 402

// Global variables

HANDLE ICON = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL),
                        IMAGE_ICON,
                        0,
                        0,
                        LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED);

The problem is when I'm on the desktop and decide to enter the hotkey. It's as if the desktop icons are contained within a window themselves, which is then resized according to ResizeWindow. This only happens once I activate (i.e., click on) the desktop before entering the hotkey. How can I determine that hWnd is a window containing the desktop icons, such that I can prevent this issue when calling HandleHotKeyMessage? I used the Visual Studio 2022 Windows Desktop Application template for this project.
I tried to check if the current window was the desktop window using
HWND foregroundWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

if (foregroundWnd == GetDesktopWindow()) {
    return;
}

from HandleHotKeyMessage to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Maybe start by logging which window you detected, then checking in a window spy tool what that window is and figure out how to identify it (by class name for example)

"How can I determine that hWnd is the desktop"
You could try to use GetForegroundWindow to get the foreground window handle and then compare it with the handle returned by GetDesktopWindow.

"How can I determine that hWnd is the desktop from within HandleHotKeyMessage" - you cant, because it never will be. It will always be your main window that you registered to receive the WM_HOTKEY message.

@RemyLebeau If this is the case, then shouldn't HandleHotKeyMessage not work? When I call GetForegroundWindow it seems to be targeting the active window and assigning it to foregroundWnd. Without the call to GetForegroundWindow, HandleHotKeyMessage does nothing.

@RemyLebeau I edited the original post for clarity. I seem to have misunderstood my own problem a bit.

@individual_9238 The duplicate question I linked to addresses your issue. Its answers are written for C#, but can easily be translated to C++ since the same Win32 APIs are involved.
